# Simplify $\sqrt x\left(\sqrt x+\frac1{\sqrt x}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

Would anyone be able to show me the answer (the question being to fully simplify this expression) and derivation?
$$\sqrt x\left(\sqrt x+\frac1{\sqrt x}\right)$$

Comment: If you click the link there is an image of the question :)

Comment: Sorry, I think it asks to simplify it.

Comment: $$x+1 ........$$

Comment: I got x+1 however my friend got a different answer, I think my answer is correct although I'm not sure

Comment: Your friend was wrong.

Comment: $x+1$ for $x\geq 0$

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: The tag ([tag:roots]) is for zeroes of functions, the tags ([tag:arithmetic]) and ([tag:radicals]) are better tags for questions about square roots, cube roots, etc. From [roots tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/roots/info): For questions about "square roots", "cube roots", and such, consider using the (radicals) and (arithmetic) tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression is defined for $x>0$. You should use the following properties

1. $\sqrt{x}=x^{1/2}$
2. $x^ax^b=x^{a+b}$
3. $\dfrac1{x^a}=x^{-a}$
4. $x^0=1$

with $a=1/2$ in your case. \begin{align}\sqrt{x}\left(\sqrt{x}+\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\right)&=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}+\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}=x^{1/2}x^{1/2}+\frac{x^{1/2}}{x^{1/2}}\\[0.2cm]&=x^{1/2+1/2}+x^{1/2-1/2}=x^1+x^0\\[0.2cm]&=x+1\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly how I did it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding it gives you

$ {\sqrt x}.{\sqrt x} + \left(\frac{\sqrt x .1}{\sqrt x}\right)$

$x+1$

Comment: Thanks, I did it differently but i understand that way as well :)